# Как объединить несколько строковых переменных в одну?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Не знаю как объяснить.
Как можно реализовать так `<title>Андрей Николаев</title>`?

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

---

```
Sql: first_name = Андрей
     last_name  = Николаев
```

---

Можно сделать так

```
<?php
$title = <?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $user_data['last_name']; ?>
?>
```

---

Или так

```
<?php
$title = $user_data['first_name','last_name'];
?>
```

Не знаю как реализовать!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$title = $user_data['first_name'].' '.$user_data['last_name'];
```

тебе надо соединить между собой три строки - одну переменную, пробел, и вторую переменную. Оператор соединения строк (конкатенации) в РНР - точка.